# How to get the directory of an argparse file in Python?

Tags: python, path, argparse

I use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) to get a file from the user:

```
import argparse, os
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=file)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then I want to know the directory where this file is, something like:

```
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(args.inputfile)))
```

But of course, as `args.inputfile` is a `file` object, this does not work. How to do it?

Comment: You could simply get the argument as a string, then open it afterwards.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, that's the easy way, but I want to be sure there's nothing smarter to do, as `argparse` provides the useful `type=file`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the name of the file from the `.name` attribute, and then pass this to `os.path.abspath`.  For example:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
path = os.path.abspath(args.file.name)
```